# twgl.js: How to use a packed vertex array via BufferInfo

Tags: javascript, twgl.js

I am using twgl.js (http://twgljs.org/) in a webgl project, it's very nice to use, but I want to optimize my code to use packed vertex arrays. However I can't seem to figure out how that works in twgl, I can see there are some options for the stride and offset in it, but no further information how exactly they will behave. I've read the code, but from that I get the feeling that it will not allow me to use a single call to createBufferInfoFromArrays, but require alot more by hand plumbing.
Is it possible to setup packed arrays with twgl.js? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes, it will require a lot more plumbing" or rather it's up to you to pack the data. You can easily make a your own `BufferInfo`

```
var packedBuffer = twgl.createBufferFromTypedArray(
    gl, typedArrayWithPackedData);

var indexBuffer = twgl.createBufferFromTypedArray(
    gl, typedArrayWithIndices, gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);

var stride = 36; // position + normal + texcoord + rgba8

var handMadeBufferInfo = {
  numElements: 123, // or whatever
  indices: indexBuffer,            // remove if no indices
  elementType: gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,  // remove if no indices
  attribs: {
    position: { buffer: packedBuffer, numComponents: 3, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: stride, offset: 0, },
    normal:   { buffer: packedBuffer, numComponents: 3, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: stride, offset: 12, },
    texcoord: { buffer: packedBuffer, numComponents: 2, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: stride, offset: 24, },
    vcolor:   { buffer: packedBuffer, numComponents: 4, type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, stride: stride, offset: 32, normalize: true },
  },
};
```

```js
var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

// there's no easy way to interleave the data unless we use pure binary so 
// lets do it manually.
var position = [
  -1, -1, 0, 
   1, -1, 0,
  -1,  1, 0,
   1,  1, 0,
];
var texcoord = [
   0,  0,
   1,  0,
   0,  1,
   1,  1,
]
var color = [
   255, 0, 0, 255,
   0, 255, 0, 255,
   0, 0, 255, 255,
   255, 255, 255, 255,
];

var stride = 24; // position + texcoord + rgba8

var typedArrayWithPackedData = new ArrayBuffer(stride * 4);
var floatView = new Float32Array(typedArrayWithPackedData);
var uint8View = new Uint8Array(typedArrayWithPackedData);
var floatAdd = 1;
var uint8Add = stride - 4;
var floatOffset = 0;
var uint8Offset = stride - 4;
var positionOffset = 0;
var texcoordOffset = 0;
var colorOffset = 0;
for (var ii = 0; ii < 4; ++ii) {
  floatView[floatOffset++] = position[positionOffset++];
  floatView[floatOffset++] = position[positionOffset++];
  floatView[floatOffset++] = position[positionOffset++];
  floatView[floatOffset++] = texcoord[texcoordOffset++];
  floatView[floatOffset++] = texcoord[texcoordOffset++];
  floatOffset += floatAdd;
  uint8View[uint8Offset++] = color[colorOffset++];
  uint8View[uint8Offset++] = color[colorOffset++];
  uint8View[uint8Offset++] = color[colorOffset++];
  uint8View[uint8Offset++] = color[colorOffset++];
  uint8Offset += uint8Add;
}

var packedBuffer = twgl.createBufferFromTypedArray(
    gl, typedArrayWithPackedData);

var typedArrayWithIndices = new Uint16Array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]);
var indexBuffer = twgl.createBufferFromTypedArray(
    gl, typedArrayWithIndices, gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);

var handMadeBufferInfo = {
  numElements: 6, // or whatever
  indices: indexBuffer,            // remove if no indices
  elementType: gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,  // remove if no indices
  attribs: {
    position: { buffer: packedBuffer, numComponents: 3, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: stride, offset: 0, },
    texcoord: { buffer: packedBuffer, numComponents: 2, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: stride, offset: 12, },
    color:    { buffer: packedBuffer, numComponents: 4, type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, stride: stride, offset: 20, normalize: true, },
  },
};

gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

// make a texture with a circle in it
var canvas2d = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas2d.width = 64;
canvas2d.height = 64;
var ctx = canvas2d.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(32, 32, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.fill();


var uniforms = {
  u_texture: twgl.createTexture(gl, { src: canvas2d }),
};

gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, handMadeBufferInfo);
twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, handMadeBufferInfo);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  v_texcoord = texcoord;
  v_color = color;
  gl_Position = position;
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord) * v_color;
}
</script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Note: `twgl.createBufferFromTypedArray` was only recently exposed in version 0.0.37

It's not really clear how it could be any easier. If you want twgl to pack the data for you it's not clear what the point is. Is it really that much faster to render? Maybe twgl should support Vertex Array Objects instead?

If you packed it yourself you'd have to give it all the same information above anyway just to have twgl transform it into a `BufferInfo` which doesn't seem like it would save you much time.

Comment: There's [a semi generic packing example here](http://twgljs.org/examples/packed-arrays.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did something very similar to your example now.
I dunno how much it helps performance. It did reduce cpu load at least, might just be premature optimization, but it feels good.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you checked out [Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_vertex_array_object/)? That would probably lower your CPU time even more. A Vertex Array Object is basically a GL level object that tracks all the vertex attribute state. So you can just bind a new VAO and all the state is set, one call.

Comment: I know they exist, but did not want to go down the road of using extensions just yet.

Comment: I brought it up because AFIAK it's emulated in both FF and Chrome. I know it emulated in Chrome because I implemented it. It exists on OSX and iOS so Safari is covered. That leaves only IE12 (not emulated) and Edge (no idea). It's also possible to [emulate it in JS](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/blob/master/sdk/demos/google/resources/OESVertexArrayObject.js). So people using IE it gets a tiny bit slower (>5%?) but for people using anything else they get the speed boost. It's also default available in WebGL 2.0 and so seems the way things will go.

Comment: added [this issue if you want to discuss it](https://github.com/greggman/twgl.js/issues/11).

Comment: I am currently focused on a bunch of other issues. I've added a todo to my list, it'll probably be a few weeks before I'll have time to work on it however.